# how can I unistall this , unity-webapps-facebookmessenger (2.4.16+13.10.20131126-0ubuntu1)

Tags: unity, firefox, webapps, facebook

how can I unistall this , unity-webapps-facebookmessenger (2.4.16+13.10.20131126-0ubuntu1) , its the application that ubuntu asked my by itself to innstall when i typed facebook.com on my browser, and its impossible to unistall , i got an facebook-icon that is beneath app empathy , when i click on it redirects me to facebook through the mozilla , i checked for any facebook-messsenger addons on mozilla and there were none , i didnt like it, and its impossible to delete ,please help me to unistall it !

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal run:

```
sudo apt-get -y purge unity-webapps-facebookmessenger
```